Leak in the wall from my upstairs toilet and shower when one is in use
My upstairs restroom toilet and  or shower have a leak when one of them are in use going down the wall into the laundry room  But my sink works with no leak ? Please any help

Depending on the location of the three, the sink drain might be after the leak.  The toilet and shower drains have a leak before the sink drain pipe.

whatever the cause, you're sill going to have to open up the wall to fix it.
